# xcode после обновления пропали кнопки в приложении

Tags: ios, xcode

Подскажите, обновлял xcode до последний версии и как следстви пришлось обновить OS X Yosemite до версии 10,10. Запустил приложение в новом xcode и пропали кнопки на главной странице в xcode. Но если запустить приложение в симуляторе или на девайсе то они там есть и нормально работают. Они остались в приложении, но вот в левом столбце они стали полупрозрачные, как их вернуть?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле сториборда на панели `Interface Builder Document` уберите галочку для поля `Size Classes`.

Comment: спасибо, а если я отключил классы и снова включил, кнопки появились, классы размера же будут работать?

Comment: Да, будут работать. `Size Classes` удобнее использовать когда ваш проект для iPhone и iPad, или поддерживает Portrait и Landscape.